# Handling durability requirements failure in Couchbase

Tags: transactions, couchbase, durability

Recently I've started investigating Couchbase Server as a candidate for the project. A particular scenario I'm looking at right now is to how to make Couchbase acting as a "source of truth" which is why I'm digging into the durability aspect.

So here is a snippet from [ACID Properties and Couchbase](https://blog.couchbase.com/acid-properties-couchbase-part-1/):

> If the durability requirements fail, then Couchbase may still save the
>   document and eventually distribute it across the cluster. All we know
>   is that it didn’t succeed as far as the SDK knows. You can choose to
>   act on this information to introduce more ACID properties into your
>   application.

So imagine next. I insert/update a document and primary node fails until data made it to any replica. Let's say primary is gone for a long time. Now, I don't know at this point whether data was written to disk... So a scary part here is that **"Couchbase may still save the document and eventually distribute it across the cluster"**. Meaning, as far as client can tell, the data didn't make it, so a user would see an error, but then all of a sudden it may appear in the system if primary goes back online.

Am I reading this statement correctly? If I am, what's the best practice to handle it with Couchbase?

Comment: I am not sure if this will answer your question but Couchbase provides the option to be notified when an element is persisted to disk or replicated to another node. https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/3.x/developer/dev-guide-3.0/observe.html

Comment: @CarlosGonzalez Thank you. I understand that in case document was replicated onto any of replica, there is a way to deal with the situation. I'm more wondering about the case when node dies and you have no idea whether doc was stored there on disk or not until the node gets back online.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So here is what I've found out talking to Couchbase guys:

**Scenario #1**

> One scenario could be that after it has been acknowledged as
>   persisted, but before it’s been replicated, the node fails. In that
>   case, if you do not failover the node, when it comes back online, that
>   item will be replicated.

**Scenario #2**

> One other scenario is that you could have autofailover enabled and
>   after it’s received by the primary but before it’s replicated or
>   persisted, autofailover kicks in and brings a replica to primary. In
>   this case, your application will have seen the failure to achieve the
>   durability requirement requested. If the previous primary does come
>   back online, before it rejoins the cluster it will resync with the
>   state of the current cluster meaning the location where the item is
>   active is now the current state.

So I've asked if "*When the former primary gets back online with locally persisted but not replicated items and starts resyncing, would these items get wiped off or something?*" -

> Yes, and that’s really intentional. You could look at those previously
>   persisted items as an “alternate history” that didn’t play out. When
>   the failure occurred, the cluster picked a new starting place, got
>   everyone to agree, and started the universe moving forward from there.
>   When the old node recovers and tries to join this universe, it has to
>   do so with a shared understanding of that universe, which potentially
>   means dropping data that wasn’t passed along.
>
> Of course, in practice, since replication is memory-to-memory and Disk
>   IO tends to be higher latency (the replication of an item and the
>   persistence of items are both scheduled concurrently), things will
>   tend to be replicated more than persisted, but there is no guarantee.
>   Also, the app (through the SDK) has some ability to influence outcomes
>   too with the Durability Requirements features we were talking about.

The full conversation is [here](https://forums.couchbase.com/t/handling-durability-requirements-failure-in-couchbase/18643/5).

Answer (score 4):

An update for this question:

Couchbase 6.5 introduced support for transactions:

```
transactions.run((txnctx) -> {
    // get the account documents for Andy and Beth  
    TransactionJsonDocument andy = txnctx.getOrError(collection, "Andy");
    JsonObject andyContent = andy.contentAsObject();
    int andyBalance = andyContent.getInt("account_balance");
    TransactionJsonDocument beth = txnctx.getOrError(collection, "Beth"); 
    JsonObject bethContent = beth.contentAsObject();
    int bethBalance = bethContent.getInt("account_balance");

    // if Beth has sufficient funds, make the transfer
    if (bethBalance > transferAmount) {
            andyContent.put("account_balance", andyBalance + transferAmount);
            txnctx.replace(andy, andyContent);
            bethContent.put("account_balance", bethBalance - transferAmount);
            txnctx.replace(beth, bethContent);
    }
    else throw new InsufficientFunds();  
    // Commit transaction - if omitted will be automatically committed 
    txnctx.commit();
});
```

The durability has also been improved, and now you can choose between 3 levels: majority, persistToActive, persistToMajority

Read more :

- https://blog.couchbase.com/distributed-multi-document-acid-transactions-in-couchbase/
- https://blog.couchbase.com/couchbase-transactions-java-api/

Answer (score 3):

**Short answer:**

Turn on auto-failover, and you'll be fine.

**Longer answer:**

It sounds like you're worried about a pretty narrow edge case here. Here's my understanding:

1. You save a document with the SDK and give it a persists_to durability requirement.
2. Couchbase acknowledges the document was saved to memory.
3. The SDK starts to check to make sure it is persisted to disk and/or is replicated.
4. During an extremely brief window of time, the node goes down. The document was **persisted to disk** but **wasn't replicated to another node** and **the primary node isn't failed over**.
5. The SDK operation will return an error, saying that it didn't meet durability requirements. (I may be wrong about this, it may return a different error, which means you could act on it differently).
6. You notify the user that something failed.
7. The node comes back up, rejoins the cluster, and the document is there.
8. Confused user?

If that's correct, the key is step 4. First of all, this seems like a pretty rare edge case. All three of those things have to be true to worry about this situation. My Couchbase internals knowledge isn't rock solid, so that situation may not be possible (but I'll keep going as if it were).

If you're running Couchbase on a good network and good machines, then network splits/nodes going down shouldn't happen very often. You can therefore turn on automatic failover. Remember that our document didn't make it to disk. So when a failover happens, the document was only in RAM, and therefore it's gone for good (and since you told the user that, no confusion).

Again, I am not an expert on Couchbase internals, so this is all to the best of my knowledge, but it sounds like all you need to do is turn on auto-failover, and you'll be fine. It's off by default; the idea is that you should understand what it is first and choose to opt-in. But for most systems, use auto-failover.

Comment: Thank you, sir! Partially it's a relief. I also admit that it's a rare case, something that will be hard to hit, although I'm going to set up a cluster in Azure in next few days to play around it just in case.

Comment: Note (at least in Java) you can also set observer to monitor replication state.  These sections of the SDK docs may help: https://docs.couchbase.com/java-sdk/2.7/durability.html https://docs.couchbase.com/java-sdk/2.7/failure-considerations.html